# In Django 3, how do I build an AND query based on an array of conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm using Python 3.8 and Django 3.  I have the following model ...

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType, blank=False)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_phone')
    email = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_email')
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

I want to build an advanced search where I can search for one or multiple attributes, based on whether they are supplied.  I have

```
class CoopManager(models.Manager):
    def find(self, name, type, enabled):
        if name:
            qset = Coop.objects.filter(name=name) 
        if type:
            qset = Coop.objects.filter(type__name=type) 
        if enabled:
            qset = Coop.objects.filter(enabled=enabled)        

        return qset
```

but the above is flawed because it will only search on one attribute.  How do I create an array of conditions and pass them to my query?  For example, if "enabled" and "name" are supplied, then the query should only search by those two things.  If "type" and "name" are supplied, ti should only search by those two things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *chain* the filters and thus use the `qset` that might be filtered already in the next filtering:

```
class CoopManager(models.Manager):
    def find(self, name=None, type=None, enabled=None):
        qset = Coop.objects.all()
        if name:
            qset = qset.filter(name=name) 
        if type:
            qset = qset.filter(type__name=type) 
        if enabled:
            qset = qset.filter(enabled=enabled)        
        return qset
```

Or even more convenient, you can make a helper function:

```
def filter_qs_without_none(qs, **kwargs):
    return qs.filter(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None})
```

then you can filter with:

```
class CoopManager(models.Manager):
    def find(self, name=None, type=None, enabled=None):
        return filter_qs_without_none(
            Coop.objects.all(),
            name=name,
            type__name=type,
            enabled=enabled
        )
```